# Login user at startup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(1.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Request is not available in this context

How else can I automatically login a user without having to do a whole new page request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What part is confusing you? Forms Auth requires a request in order to work. Part of what it does is send a cookie to the client, and it can't very well do that if there's no client. `Application_Start` runs outside of the request, so you can't access the request object from there. Even if you could, this isn't run for each request, so it would only work for the first user that caused it to activate.

If you want to do this in a global way, but within the request scope, you'll need to use something like a custom action filter or a custom membership provider. Not sure which would be best for something like or even if an action filter would work, but that's your options.